# Express.js Delete File (Local FS) after Download

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I've got the following code for an Express handler which aims to download a file after a valid file path is found in the directory entries - the handler has a command-line option which is in place to delete said file, after a successful download:

```
     res.download(filePath, err => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err)
      }
      if (AUTO_DELETE_ENABLED) {
        rmSync(filePath)
        console.log('deleted after download...')
      }
    })
```

In a browser, when entering the valid file path, the download seems to *begin*, but the file is deleted right away, without waiting.

Can someone explain to me how I can do this? Express `res.download` takes a callback, I'm using that callback to dynamically determine if the command line setting is enabled, if so - I delete the file.

So why does this not work? And what can I do to ensure this happens?

For now, I have a 3000ms `setTimeout` which can make sure the desired functionality is achieved, but some videos may take longer than that to download...

Q: Is the fact I'm using `rmSync` potentially part of the problem? The rest of the code is for the most part asynchronous.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How does the problem manifest itself in the browser? Does the browser cancel the download, or is everything downloaded?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Well, in an HTTP Client, like Postman - the request returns the binary just fine, and the file _is_ subsequently deleted from the local file directory (as it should be). But, within the browser, the file _seems_ to TRY to download, but the callback code within `res.download` executes, deleting the file before it can download, and the file is tiny I may also add, so the callback is not waiting at all - maybe I'm completely wrong and `res.download` callback is not _supposed_ to wait, but the problem remains.

Comment: How does the browser react to that? I assume that the downloads folder you are downloading _to_ differs from the folder you are downloading _from_ (even though both are on the same computer).

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use unlink function:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

You can use callback function to signal when deleting is finished or if some error occured.

Comment: Why would `unlink` work while `rmSync` doesn't?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your problem. Express documentation says that download method takes a option object as parameter. Have you tried disabling cache?

Comment: @robertklep I am now using `rm`, which takes a callback - `unlink` from my understanding takes a callback too, and I've now tried it also. It's a confusing one as the page that calls this Express method is just an HTML doc with an input, a GET is called on submit of a form. It seems odd with this being asynchronous and using a callback in `res.download` that using `setTimeout` is the only way I've been able to get this to work so far.

Comment: @m.js you haven't explained what the actual problem is. How does calling `rm` (or `rmSync` or `unlink`, which should all be interchangeable) cause problems with the download? Please augment your question detailing the actual issue.

Comment: @robertklep How exactly have I not detailed what the actual problem is? I've mentioned I have an HTML doc that triggers a GET request to my Express server, I've mentioned that in the browser, when performing the GET, the download seems to _start_, but the code that deletes the file is executed _before_ the download completes, and the download doesn't occur. I _am_ new to posting here, but please have a bit of decency in understanding I am actively describing "what the actual problem is".

Comment: @m.js _"the download seems to begin, but the file is deleted right away, without waiting"_. How are we to conclude from that that the download doesn't occur? How can a download start yet not occur at the same time? Also, on a lot of OS'es, it's perfectly fine to remove a file while it's still being used. Also, the callback to `res.download()` should fire when the file has been sent (or rather, the file has been read entirely). But you don't include enough details in your question.